# Grouping and getting the most frequent row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    col1     col2
0   maria    apple
1   eugene   apple
2   eugene   banana
3   maria    apple
4   maria    pear
5   eugene   banana
6   maria    apple
```

I want to group by person to see what is the most common fruit for that person, something like this:

```
    col1     col2    col3
0   maria    apple   3
1   eugene   banana  2
```

**edit** What I accomplished so far was:

```
    col1     col2
   maria    apple   2
            pear    1
   eugene   banana  2
            apple   1
```

with

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts()
```

but I couldn't figure it out how to get only the max values, since its a series, not a dataframe

Comment: @Drise, it's because more and more we are getting "functional users" - neither professional nor enthusiast programmers. More people who just want to get things done. Python gets targeted more because of its easy syntax.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't think people wanted to see my failed attempts, will edit the post with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
```

Output:

```
col1          
eugene  banana    2
maria   apple     3
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

`mode` from `scipy`

```
from scipy import stats

df.groupby('col1').col2.apply(stats.mode)
Out[530]: 
col1
eugene    ([banana], [2])
maria      ([apple], [3])
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `groupby()` on your `col1`, obtain frequencies using `value_counts()`, then sort values in a descending order with the `sort_values()` function

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["maria","eugene","eugene","maria","maria","eugene","maria"],
          "col2": ["apple", "apple","banana","apple","pear","banana","apple"]})  
a.groupby(["col1"])["col2"].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)
```